# IfModule doesn't appear to be working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/training/(.*) /faculty/training.html
</IfModule>
```

the redirects don't occur.

Same with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
...
</IfModule>
```

However, this works as expected:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/training/(.*) /faculty/training.html
```

In other words, the redirect works fine outside of the `<IfModule>` block.

Is there a reason why `<IfModule>` wouldn't detect mod_rewrite.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RedirectMatch` directive is part of `mod_alias.c` and not `mod_rewrite.c`, You want your IfModule to check for mod_alias.c. You also don't need to turn on RewriteEngine since RedirectMatch doesn't use it.