# Can't get mod_rewrite IfModule to work in .htaccess

Tags: php, c, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get my `.htaccess` file to forward all URLs to a single page with url parameters so that I can handle the page retrievals that way. What I want to happen is this: say the user types in `http://mysite.com/users/dan` it should forward to the page `http://mysite.com/index.php?url=/users/dan`.

Similarly, if the user accessed the URL `http://mysite.com/random-link` it should forward to `http://mysite.com/index.php?url=random-link`

Here is the code I tried in my `.htaccess` file, but it just keeps throwing a 500 error at me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond % (REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?url=$1 <QSA,L>
</IfModule>
```

**I UPDATED MY CODE TO THIS AND IT STILL THROWS A 500 ERROR**
I changed the < and > to [ and ] and I removed the space after the % in the RewriteCond, but it still throws an error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm a novice when it comes to `.htaccess`, so any help would be greatly appreciated, because I don't know what's causing the server to timeout.

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: I don't have error logging enabled, is that what you mean?

Comment: ¿What does index.php do with parameter `/users/dan/` for example, redirects to that folder? If so, `/users/dan/`is being redirected to `/users/dan/`. There is a loop and the reason for error 500. But, to be sure, do what Phil suggested. Check the Apache log.

Comment: No, index.php doesn't redirect, it retrieves the proper file depending on which page is indexed with the display URL given in the url parameter on index.php.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your rules. Try this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]` instead of %{REQUEST_FILENAME} and see what happens.

Comment: And if still doesn't work, try replacing `RewriteEngine on` with `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @danL Apache always has some kind of error log. There will be an entry for your 500 errors

Comment: I'm having to reboot the server right now because I accidentally overloaded it trying all this! Thanks for the answers supplied thus far, I'll keep you guys updated when the server is back online.

Comment: Check this question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983328/ifmodule-doesnt-appear-to-be-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of problems

1. Rewrite flags go in square-brackets, eg

   ```
   [QSA,L]
   ```
2. Your `RewriteCondition` syntax looks incorrect. Try

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   ```
3. Just to be on the safe side, anchor your expression to the start of the string

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

Lastly, `RewriteEngine` and subsequent modifiers requires the `FileInfo` [override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Override). Make sure your server config or virtual host [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) section for your document root has

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

### Update

Here's a typical rewrite scheme from an MVC project. This will ignore real files, directories and symlinks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I updated both parts of the code, but it still throws a 500/timeout at me. Any thoughts why? Thanks for your help thus far, though.

Comment: Did you mean to make the l in [QSA,l] lowercase? I tried updating the code with the start anchor but still no luck. :(

Comment: @danL I've updated my answer with information about the `FileInfo` override

Comment: Thank you! It works now. The 500 error was also being caused by an infinite redirect on a file_get_contents() call.

Comment: How would I get the code to omit anything in certain directories? For instance, if I only want it to catch URLs that don't start with /folder1/ or /folder2/? Thanks!